# Which point lies on which linestring?

Tags: r, sf

Using the `{sf}` package, I have two `sf` objects:

1. one containing `linestrings` (edges), which form a linear network;
2. one containing `points`, which are restricted to lie on the network.

My goal ist to identify which point lies on which edge. How can I do this? Of course, multiple points on one `linestring` are possible.

Why I want to do this? I would like to transmit point weights to the respective line segments/`linestrings`/edges to plot those in a later step via `{igraph}`'s `E(g)$weight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `st_intersects` which returns a list for each point of which features the point is on.

EG the `nc` data cast to linear features:

```
> nc
Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
```

with some random points taken from `st_coordinates(nc)`:

```
> st_intersects(pts, nc)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 100, where the
predicate was `intersects'
first 10 elements:
 1: 36, 44
 2: 68, 69
 3: 62, 88
```

In this case the first three points are on two features (because the way I made the lines meant there's nearly always two lines at each point because most of them are shared borders between two polygons):

[image]

Note this is *not* testing for the polygon, but for the lines that make up the polygon. If the point is off the line, then nothing is returned, and the list element is empty with zero length.

If your points aren't mathematically precisely on the lines then maybe use `st_nearest_feature` to get the nearest line feature.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, `st_intersects` just returns `(empty)`. My problem with `st_nearest_feature` is that it just lists the nearest neighbour, which is problematic if more than one point lies on the line sgement.